# Difference of datetime column in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a table of 20000 records. each Record has a datetime field. I want to select all records where gap between one record and subsequent record is more than one hour [condition to be applied on datetime field].

can any one give me the SQL command code for this purpose.

regards

KAM

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: In Oracle PL/SQL you have to use WINDOW FUNCTIONS....  I can't tell more if you don't specify what DBMS are you using.

Comment: Sir, my database is Teradata. Will this code work in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be done with a sub query, which should work on **all** DBMS. As gordon said, date/time functions are different in every one.

```
SELECT t.* FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.DateCol + interval '1 hour' < (SELECT min(s.DateCol) FROM YourTable s
                   WHERE t.ID = s.ID AND s.DateCol > t.DateCol)
```

You can replace this:

```
t.DateCol + interval '1 hour'
```

With one of this so it will work on almost every DBMS:

```
DATE_ADD( t.DateCol, INTERVAL 1 hour)
DATEADD(hour,1,t.DateCol)
```

Answer (score 4):

ANSI SQL supports the `lead()` function.  However, date/time functions vary by database.  The following is the logic you want, although the exact syntax varies, depending on the database:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(datetimefield) over (order by datetimefield) as next_datetimefield
      from t
     ) t
where datetimefield + interval '1 hour' < next_datetimefield;
```

Note:  In Teradata, the `where` would be:

```
where datetimefield + interval '1' hour < next_datetimefield;
```

Comment: Sir, my database is Teradata. Will this code work in it?

Answer (score 2):

Although Teradata doesn't support Standard SQL's `LEAD` it's easy to rewrite:

```
select tab.*,
   min(ts) over (order by ts rows between 1 following and 1 following) as next_ts
from tab
qualify 
   ts < next_ts - interval '1' hour
```

If you don't need to show the next timestamp:

```
select *
from tab
qualify 
   ts < min(ts) over (order by ts rows between 1 following and 1 following) - interval '1' hour
```

`QUALIFY` is a Teradata extension, but really nice to have, similar to `HAVING` after `GROUP BY`

Comment: Sir,The code worked however no record is shown it may mean that there was no record that could qualify. However if hours are needed to be changed to minutes e.g. 15 minutes what would be the syntax.

Comment: @KhawarAmeerMalik: `interval '15' minute`